# VS 2015 Could not find SDK "Microsoft.AdMediator.Universal, Version=1.0"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I developed an application for the UWP platform. At the same time, I needed to add an advertising banner to the application, so I used Microsoft's SDK.

I did not fix the error (**" Error  Could not find SDK "Microsoft.AdMediator.Universal, Version=1.0".**)" afterwards.
I checked the version and performed the update process. But I did not fix the problem.
What do I need to do about the subject (s)?
Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Ad mediation for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.x apps is no longer under active development. To maximize your potential advertising revenue, we recommend that you build UWP apps that use ad mediation in an AdControl or InterstitialAd. If you want to migrate it to a UWP app that uses AdControlPlease see [Migrate from AdMediatorControl to AdControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/migrate-from-admediatorcontrol-to-adcontrol).

Comment: Hello ;
Since I can not resolve the issue by now, I can not remove. Image( https://msstorage.blob.core.windows.net/halic/img1.jpg?st=2017-05-26T22%3A15%3A00Z&se=2018-12-28T22%3A15%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=VuKPe2jBmifQRuPiS2RrHzDWuQk%2FxE5zpWP7%2B703q0I%3D )

Comment: For reference, I removed the library and updated the SDK. I checked the versions. I did not yet manage to remove the related Microsoft Advertising Framework when I controlled the Extensions and the incoming updates afterwards.  Image ( https://msstorage.blob.core.windows.net/halic/img2.png?st=2017-05-26T22%3A15%3A00Z&se=2018-12-30T22%3A15%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=GBMJYJXX4mjz2N2fJrthGSroqYbOaQVPzqngAapcMYQ%3D )